# Where can I find a cipher in Twin Elms?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

For Edér's quest I need to find a cipher, and the journal tells me that I should look in Twin Elms:

[image]

I've looked there, but I was unable to find any cipher that would help me. Where can I find one?

Answer (score 2):

The Cipher in Twin Elms is located at:

> In Old Song, on the western side of the map. On the dirt path, directly between the two wooden jetties. The dude is a Mindhunter, he's standing on the shore with his toes in the water.

Answer (score 1):

The Grieving Mother, a character you can recruit in Dyrford, is a cipher.

Answer (score 0):

The Twin Elms mindhunters count as ciphers! I believe there's one in Oldsong that's just standing around that you can talk to.